# OwnCloud Registeration Form

Tags: encryption, owncloud

I am currently looking into making a register form, I was wondering if anyone knows how the encryption works? As I need to just add a simple register script, but of course it's a little beyond me.

I need to know how:
+ The encryption works so how to encrypt the password and store it,
+ Does anything else need to be done other than storing the new user as I would expect it is done simply by just logging in with the new user and it would work right?

Anyway any help would be great thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here ya go: http://knyz.org/blog/owncloud-registration/

Or if you want it more *to the point*. Here is the GitHub repo: https://github.com/viruzx/Owncloud-Registration